# Certificate Authentication in Azure DNS API

Tags: authentication, dns

I am following the instructions and sample code provided in this article,

https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/dns-sdk/

That article is using OAuth authentication for consuming the Azure DNS APIs. However, I have a different set of requirements to make a few calls in the backend, so a client certificate (or management cert) works best for me in this scenario. As soon as I change the code to use CertificateCloudCredentials, all the API calls return Unauthorized. The same certificate works fine with other management API calls. Is it possible to use this authentication in the API preview or am I making something wrong here.

```
var credentials = new CertificateCloudCredentials(subID, cert);
var zoneRoot = dnsClient.Zones.Get("MyGrup", "myZone");
```

The API call above returns 401.

I appreciate any help to get this solved.

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

the Azure DNS API is part of the Azure Resource Management (ARM) set of APIs which uses Azure Active Directory (AAD) for authentication. Here is a [good article by Tom Hollander](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/tomholl/archive/2015/06/19/authenticating-to-azure-resource-manager-using-aad-and-certificates.aspx) on how to use client certificates with AAD and ARM.

> The same certificate works fine with other management API calls

Do you mean here other Azure Resource Management APIs or Azure Service Management APIs? The distinction is important, as the two sets of APIs use different methods of authentication. If you set up your cert for Service Management authorization, it would not just work with Resource Management authorization. How to tell: Resource Management libraries would use namespaces under Microsoft.Azure, Service Management libraries would use Microsoft.WindowsAzure. In PowerShell, [Switch-AzureMode](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/Dn722470.aspx) would tell you which API you are using.

Comment: This is exactly what I was looking for. Yes, I was using the service management APIs before. Very helpful. Thanks a lot.